# create query with json format

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I'm trying to get json object result value as

```
{
    year: 2015,
    count : 10,
    children[{
        month: Jan,
        count: 1,
        children: [{
            date: 01,
            count: 1
        },
        {
            date: 11,
            count: 1
        }]
    },
    {
        month: feb,
        count: 2,
        children: []
    }]
}
```

from date and its count. I have done partially for year and date. For month I need to retrieve the children with respect to month.

```
select row_to_json(t) 
from (  select EXTRACT(year FROM pr_created_on) as year, (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(jd)))
  from (
    select count(project_id), EXTRACT(month FROM pr_created_on) as month,(select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(js)))
  from (
    select to_char(pr_created_on, 'dd') as date,EXTRACT(month FROM pr_created_on) as month, count(project_id) from projects 
    where  EXTRACT(year FROM pr_created_on) = '2015'  and to_char(pr_created_on, 'dd') between '01' and '30' group by month,date order by date  
  ) js) as children
    from projects 
    where EXTRACT(month FROM pr_created_on) between '01'  and '12' AND EXTRACT(year FROM pr_created_on) = '2015' group by month      
  ) jd
) as children from projects j  where EXTRACT(year FROM pr_created_on) = '2015' group by year) as t`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you couldn't get the results as an array and then convert to json?

For example, in PHP...

```
$results = array(
  "year"=>2015,
   // etc
);

json_encode($results);
```

Comment: im trying to create a hierarchial bar chart in d3 using dates as year, month , days. for that in i need the result set in json format

Comment: Okay, so you're using AJAX to retrieve the data?

Comment: If so, using jQuery can return a json encoded string will return the data in the format you require, but if not running 'JSON.parse(exampleJsonEncodedString)' will also put it into the format you require